# Adding -ObjC linker flag results in "no valid aps-environment' entitlement dialog

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm restructuring my app by turning 90% of it into a static library (which can then be shared between more than one app).

Within the library I have some categories so have to use the -ObjC linker flag when linking against it. But when I add this flag then when the app is run I get the "... no valid aps-environment entitlement ..' dialog appearing.

This usually appears when using push notifications (which I am) and the project hasn't been signed with the appropriate profile. 
However I don't get this dialog if I leave off the -ObjC linker flag, it only appears when I add the flag.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is only indirectly related to the `-ObjC` flag. It seems that using the flag is causing code to get executed that wouldn't otherwise, perhaps code in a category. It would be best to just focus on why the 'no valid aps-environment entitlement' dialog is getting triggered and address that issue.